# TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in Kendo UI

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik, typeerror

I'm getting the following error using Angular 1.4, jQuery 1.11.3 and the latest Kendo UI. Is this a known bug to Telerik?

The only Kendo controls I'm using on the page are kendo-multi-select, kendo-date-picker

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 
    at r (http://localhost/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2:4254)
    at Function.m.extend.map (http://localhost/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2:3686)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js:55:18312)
    at n.(anonymous function) (http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js:55:13937)
    at function.t.value.d (http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js:55:11087)
    at Object.fn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:131:178)
    at n.$get.n.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:132:259)
    at n.$get.n.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:135:269)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js:252:126)
    at HTMLButtonElement.m.event.dispatch (http://localhost/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4:8549)
```

Comment: I switched to jQuery 1.10.2 and it doesn't throw the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to kendo UI documentation ([More info here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/prerequisites)) that combination is not supported

the official support for jQuery versions with 2015 are

> Kendo UI 2015.2.624 (Q2 2015) - jQuery 1.9.1 (also works with 1.10.x
>   and 2.0.x) Kendo UI 2015.1.318 (Q1 2015) - jQuery 1.9.1 (also works
>   with 1.10.x and 2.0.x)

And for Angular js are

> Kendo UI 2015.2.624 (Q2 2015) - AngularJS 1.3.16 Kendo UI 2015.1.318
>   (Q1 2015) - AngularJS 1.3.0